# Read double digits using PHP form a text file

Tags: php, html

So, I am creating a survey for my web page, and I am using a text file to store the results like this:

1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28

I have to use PHP to pull the results from the text file and display it to the user. The survey consists of just radio buttons(an option the user can pick). Each number represents the results for that radio button. Anyway, my issue is reading the text file. I can get it work when it is just a single digit (12345678...), but it doesn't display them as double digits if it needs to be. Question is how can I get the php to not include the "|" and also show the numbers as double digits if they need to be? I'm new to php.

Also, I will eventually be reading the file to update the results if a new user submits the form, but right now I'm just trying to get it to display right. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        setcookie("Submit", "yes");
    }
    // the file that will store the data
    $fileName = "data/results.txt";

    $republican = 0;
    $democratic = 0;
    $libertarian = 0;
    $right = 0;
    $wrong = 0;
    $undecided = 0;
    $trump = 0;
    $hilary = 0;
    $mucmullin = 0;
    $otherVote = 0;
    $wontVote = 0;
    $debateYes = 0;
    $debateNo = 0;
    $changeYes = 0;
    $changeNo = 0;
    $age1829 = 0;
    $age3044 = 0;
    $age4559 = 0;
    $age60 = 0;
    $cauc = 0;
    $afAm = 0;
    $his = 0;
    $natAm = 0;
    $other = 0;
    $male = 0;
    $female = 0;

    //$results = fopen($fileName, "a+") or die("Unable to save results of your survey.");

    //Check to see if we got here from POST
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        //open file
        //save file content as an int variable, or could save it as an array
        // close file

        // check all radio buttons and see if the it was selected,
        // if so then ++ the variable we got from text file.

        // save data to the text file

        //display results
        $formPost = TRUE;
    } else { /* This will only excute if the user did not submit the form */

        // delcare array that will store the contents of the text file
        $results = array();

        // open file and read it into the array
        $results = readTextFile($fileName);

    }

 /*********************************************
  * READ TEXT FILE FUNCTION
  * This section will get data from from the file.
  * It will simply read it, and won't be able to edit
  * the file at all. It will store the contents,
    * of the file into an array, and then close the
    * file.
  *********************************************/
    function readTextFile($fileName) {
        // declaring local array
        $results = array();

        // open file
        $file = fopen($fileName, "r");

        // read the file
        while (!feof($file)) {
             $results[] = fgetc($file);
        }

        // I wasn't born in a barn
        fclose($file);

        // make like a leaf
        return $results;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Kinda confused what you are doing, but you could just explode on "|" to get an array of the answers? `print_r(expode("|", "1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28"));`

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit my post because it didn't display all my code.

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole file, then use the `explode` function as follows to split the results string on `|` characters.

```
$results = file_get_contents($fileName);
$results = explode("|", $results);
```

The array `$results` will then contain all of the numbers (as strings) that were separated by `|` in the original string.

If then you need to find out whether the array *contains* a number -- e.g. whether radio button 1 was selected -- you can create a second array, like this:

```
$results2 = [];
foreach ($results as $num) {
    $results2[$num] = true;
}
```

Then, you should be able to check `$results2[1]`, and it will be `true` if radio button 1 was selected.